# Sympy: Factorization of polynomials containing square roots

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to simplify (or factorize in this case) polynomials containing square roots. Consider the following simple example:

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x,y', real=True, positive=True)

sp.factor( sp.expand( (x**(1/2) + y**(1/2))**2 )  )
```

I would expect that `factor()` would essentially cancel `expand()`. However, this is not the case as `factor()` simply fails to factorize the expanded expression back to its original form.

Is there any way to factorize or simplify such expressions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace `sqrt(x)` with `a` and `sqrt(y)` with `b` and factor that and then restore the original expressions you will get this result. SymPy doesn't do this (I suppose) because there are many ways a symbol like `x` could be rewritten.

```
>>> from sympy import Dummy, sqrt, expand, factor
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> z = factor( expand( (sqrt(x) + sqrt(y))**2 )  )
>>> a,b=Dummy(),Dummy()
>>> factor(z.subs(sqrt(x),a).subs(sqrt(y),b)).xreplace({a:sqrt(x),b:sqrt(y)})
(sqrt(x) + sqrt(y))**2
```

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed one possible solution to that problem. Although, it seems to be limited to the case where the square root is defined with `sqrt(x)` and does not seem to be extendable to a more general case where one would have `x**(a/b)` .